# Camunda delegateExecution's getVariable throws ENGINE-03040 No serializer defined for variable instance

Tags: camunda, json-serialization

I'm new to Camunda.  I've defined BPMN for set of tasks.  Created necessary delegates to handle the activities.

As a business process I need to check pre qualification to proceed to next activity.  If pre qualification fails I need to wait and periodically check for the pre qualification conditions.  The flow succeeds if the pre qualification is true in the first run itself.  If the pre qualification is false, Camunda waits for 2 seconds and triggers for pre qualification activity, while doing so I get following error and the instance fails.

Stacktrace:

```
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-03040 No serializer defined for variable instance 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.util.TypedValueField@44ba275a'
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.EnginePersistenceLogger.serializerNotDefinedException(EnginePersistenceLogger.java:387)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.util.TypedValueField.ensureSerializerInitialized(TypedValueField.java:207)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.util.TypedValueField.getSerializer(TypedValueField.java:194)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.util.TypedValueField.getTypedValue(TypedValueField.java:105)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableInstanceEntity.getTypedValue(VariableInstanceEntity.java:276)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.variable.scope.AbstractVariableScope.getValueFromVariableInstance(AbstractVariableScope.java:146)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.variable.scope.AbstractVariableScope.getVariable(AbstractVariableScope.java:133)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.variable.scope.AbstractVariableScope.getVariable(AbstractVariableScope.java:129)
```

We are struggling on this for quite sometime now.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.
Saravan

Comment: Do you use json as variable content? Did you add the SPIN dependency?